# WPF Allow user to scroll a list box, but not change selected item.

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, listbox, scrollbar

In my current project I am using two list boxes to show progress through a set of items. The selected item shows the currently running item. For obvious reasons the user needs to not be able to change the selected item via the gui. I accomplished this by trapping out the mouse events.

Problem is, I still want the user to be able to use the scroll bar to see their all of the data points. Is there a way to allow for this interaction? Basically what I want is an enable list box, that allows the user to use the scroll bar, but not alter the data area.

I have done some research and could not find a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately after posting I found the solution. I was already using a ListBoxItem Style. If you add a setter that sets "IsHitTestVisible" to false, you can no longer select the list items, but the list box itself is unaffected.

Here is my style:

```
 <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>          
            </Style.Setters>
 </Style>
```

Simply apply that style to your list boxes "ItemContainerStyle" And you should be good to go.